# CSS3 animation on rotation in IE 10 / 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to create two animated gauges with CSS3 and found a nice solution. The gauges looks perfect in Chrome, Safari and FF but in IE I have a weird bounce effect, which almost seems

The gauges are made with `border-radius` and `clipping`.

Here is my code

http://codepen.io/kamante/pen/dyFBL/

I current have transition on all css props of the box of the guauge

```
transition: 1s all
```

and I'm suspecting other properties being animated in the process.

How can I target only the rotation on transition, and does anyone have a clue why the box 'jiggles'?

Comment: Not sure how to fix it, it's just rendering error in IE. Your setInterval should be this though `setInterval(function(){ var deg = -Math.random() *  100; .css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + deg   +'deg) ') deg = -Math.random() *   100; $('.gauge2 .box').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + deg   +'deg)'); }, 1000);`

Comment: Hmm,  I don't see why using a different random number for the webkit animation to make this work.

Comment: To me it seems like some sort of rendering bug in IE with border-radius and rotation. Anyone else got a clue?